# Mysql find dates using where in clause, or dates nearest to those in array

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have the following code and query:

```
//$month is an array of datetime objects

foreach($month as $key => $indMonth){
    $formattedMonth[] = $month[$key]->format('Y-m-d');
}

$formattedMonths = implode("','",$formattedMonth);

$query = "SELECT id,date FROM table WHERE date in ('$formattedMonths') ORDER by date DESC";
```

The database holds dates for the past 450 days, but it is imperfect and there are some missing days. The point of the script is to retrieve data from the current day of the month and then the corresponding day on the five previous months, but I need a failsafe for when a date happens to be missing.

How can I modify this query so it picks either the date in the "where in" portion of the query or it finds the date nearest to that particular date in the array?

Is this best to do in the query, or am I better off returning a more complete data set, then using PHP to find out if the date I want is available?

Comment: you won't be able to get stuff for missing dates, since by definition you can't look for/retrieve what isn't there. e.g. you want jan/mar/apr, but you have records only for aug/sep/oct - your where clause will guarantee a 0-record result set. You'd need to calculate the difference between ALL dates in your db and EACH of the dates you're using in the `in()` clause, and order by the magnitude of that difference. e.g. in pseudo-sql, `select abs(date-$date_from_php) as diff ... order by diff asc`. diff of 0 is an exact date match, any then you get "closer" dates in order.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL offers some decent date arithmetic.  For example, if you have the date `'2015-11-10'` (10-Nov-2015) you can get the same day three months prior with this expression:

```
'2015-11-10` - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

That will kick back `'2015-08-10'`, which is what you want.

This date arithmetic works predictably even with longer and shorter months, and with leap years. For example,

```
'2015-03-31' - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '2016-03-31' - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

gives back `'2015-02-28', '2016-02-29'` as you might expect. And

```
'2015-03-31' - INTERVAL 2 MONTH, '2016-03-31' - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
```

gives back `'2015-03-31', '2016-03-31'`.  Perfect.

Now, only you can decide whether this *predictable* behavior is *correct* for your application: only you know what you want to do with the previous five months of data, when the day in question is near the end of the month.

Let's assume it's correct and move on. Here is a subquery that can be used to generate a sequence of six dates, one day per month ending today.

```
    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL seq.seq MONTH day_of_month
      FROM ( SELECT 0 AS seq UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL
             SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 6) seq
```

We can use this little query as a subquery, and `LEFT JOIN` it to your data. That would work like this:

```
 SELECT id, day_of_month
   FROM (
      SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL seq.seq MONTH day_of_month
        FROM ( SELECT 0 AS seq UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL
               SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 6) seq
        ) days
   LEFT JOIN table ON table.date = days.day_of_month
```

This is a cool way to do it because you'll always get at least one row in the resultset for each date in the list, even if there's nothing matching in `table.`

The *closest* date gets a little hairier. It's possible to write a query like that. But MySQL lacks a `WITH` clause so the query is ridiculously repetitive.